# How to access web page served by nginx web server running in docker container

Tags: macos, ubuntu, nginx, docker, containers

We are trying to use docker to run nginx but for some reason I'm unable to access the **nginx** web server running inside the docker container.

We have booted a Docker Container using the following `Dockerfile`: https://github.com/dwyl/learn-docker/blob/53cca71042482ca70e03033c66d969b475c61ac2/Dockerfile

(Its a basic hello world using nginx running on port 8888)
To run the container we used:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

we determined the Container's IP address using the `docker inspect` command:

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' a9404c168b21
```

which is: **172.17.0.11**

when I try to visit the container's IP address and the nginx port in a browser http://172.17.0.11:8888/ we get **ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT**

or using curl:

```
curl 172.17.0.11:8888
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.11 port 8888: Connection refused
```

To attempt to solve this we googled *extensively* but suspect we might be asking the "wrong" questions...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't be trying to hit the IP address of the container, you should be using the IP address of the host machine.

What you are missing is the mapping of the port of the host machine to the port of the container running the nginx server.

Assuming that you want to use port 8888 on the host machine, you need a parameter such as this to map the ports:

`docker run ... -p 8888:8888 ...`

Then you should be able to access you server at `http://<HOST_MACHINE_IP>:8888`

**EDIT**: There is another gotcha if you are running on a Mac. To use Docker on a Mac it's common to use `boot2docker` but `boot2docker` adds in another layer. You need determine the IP address of the boot2docker container and use that instead of localhost to access nginx.

```
$ boot2docker ip

The VM's Host only interface IP address is: <X.X.X.X>

$ wget http://<X.X.X.X>:8888
...
Connecting to <X.X.X.X>:8888... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

Reference: https://viget.com/extend/how-to-use-docker-on-os-x-the-missing-guide

**EDIT**: ... or with `docker-machine` the equivalent command would be `docker-machine ip <machine-name>` where `<machine-name>` is likely to be "default".

Comment: thanks for reply & for clarifying that! just tried: `docker run -it -p 8888:8888 learn-docker bash` but still cannot access page when visiting: http://127.0.0.1:8888/ or http://localhost:8888/ what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I tried it out and I have the same problem. But nginx is running. I connected to the container at the commandline ( `docker exec -it <CONTAINER> bash`) then installed wget (`apt-get install wget`) and was able to get a response from nginx from *within* the container (`wget http://localhost:8888`) so it looks like it's actually a networking problem of some sort. Not sure of any more details at this stage though ...

Comment: Are you running on a Mac? The problem could be with boot2docker. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Yes, Host OS is Mac. But I'm using **Docker Toolkit** to run docker as **Boot2Docker** is deprecated.

Comment: I think it's the same scenario, i.e. there's another VM that you need to find the IP address of with `docker-machine ip <machine name>`. Probably your machine name is `default`.

Comment: Thank you for this. I spent the last hour thinking I was somehow creating my container wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check if your container is running:

- docker ps ( you should have an active container)

If no container is active:

1. docker run -p 80:80 -it  /bin/bash
2. you will then be on your image terminal
3. start nginx - sudo service nginx start
4. ctrl p + ctrl q to quit docker without exiting the container
5. if you are on mac and using boot2docker you cannot use localhost to check your running nginx
6. so use boot2docker ip
7. browse using the boot2docker ip

Comment: Is this still relevant with latest Docker for OS X?